# Packing multiple images into a GOLANG binary

Tags: image, go

GOLANG gurus:

I know this might seem illogical, but here it goes.

I have to distribute a binary (which in this case would be a webserver) to other engineers for testing. To keep it simple, because they might not be developers, I wanted to see if there might be some automated way to pack images into a GOLANG binary ? I've done this static HTML pages in the past, and it works great.

Obviously, at first run I could unzip to the file system, but to keep things clean I was trying to see if anyone has any thoughts how I could stuff them into a binary.

Any Ideas ?

Comment: Have you looked at https://github.com/rakyll/statik or https://github.com/mjibson/esc? They compile assets into a source file, which gets compiled into the binary, and also provide an implementation of a `FileSystem` so that you can access these files as if they were on the actual filesystem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the same tools you used for HTML files... I'm assuming you used something like:

- https://github.com/jteeuwen/go-bindata
- https://github.com/GeertJohan/go.rice
- https://github.com/mjibson/esc
- https://github.com/rakyll/statik
- etc.

Which essentially transform your files in go source code and the expose an http.FileSystem-like API for reading your data.

Comment: Actually, super impressed with ESC. Only took a few minutes to setup, and running perfectly

Comment: I've used go-bindata for exactly this use case to package everything into a single binary to run on a docker base container. Good stuff!